# Run commands in parallel with clean output

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script to help manage a series of websites I work on. The script uses a CLI tool provided by our web host to query for a list of sites and then executes a given command on each one.

I've tried using:

```
command 1 & command 2 & command 3 & command 4
```

Which ultimately works fine. The problem I'm running into is that the CLI tool will output statuses as each command executes. These statuses are just appended to the bottom of my terminal window randomly, detached from their original context, and allows for terminal input in between, which makes it very hard to keep track of which command has finished, which is still running, and if anything is running.

Is there any way to run this series of commands but keep the output of each command grouped, almost like a status screen, until all commands have finished running?

I've seen other CLI tools do something similar where it shows status bars/info of a bunch of independent tasks at once but I'm not sure how this is accomplished.

Thank you!

Comment: You'll probably get a better answer if you are clearer about the first 3-4 commands you want to run and how/where you specify the host.

Answer (score 0):

The [parallel](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) command appears to collect the output of each command and print it without intermixing with the other commands.

```
parallel -- "command 1" "command 2" "command 3" "command 4"
```

It doesn't provide interactive updates or indications from what command the output is from, though.  You'd have to wrap the commands with additional logic to get that behavior with the parallel command.